# How to Open Google Earth in a Remote Desktop Session?

Tags: google-earth, remote-desktop

I have a Windows 7 PC with Google Earth installed.

Sometimes I need to connect with Microsoft Remote Desktop from my MacBook Pro to the Windows 7 PC.

If I've Google Earth (Pro or not) already opened on the Windows 7 PC, I can perfectly use the software without any issues.

If I start Google Earth (Pro or not) from remote, I get a message about graphic card not supported and after another that suggest me to try using directX. I can reply to use directX or not, but Googe Earth starts without showing me the satellite map in a sort of "compatibility mode", also very slow.

Is there a way to tell Google Earth to use the Windows 7 graphic card driver and not the virtual one, when starting it from a remote Desktop Session?

Comment: I think this crosses the line from a GIS question to Windows driver/emulation question.   You might have more luck on an Apple forum.

Comment: I think there is some value tot his question here. Even ArcGlobe  refuses to open via remote desktop, but is fine if it was already open. it's definitely not a Mac specific Issue.

Comment: @kiks73: I have edited the question to clarify the question. Feel free to revert the edit, if it's not what you were asking.

Comment: see https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/earth/WaaO_LcJbt0

Comment: Try [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en) I never used it, but it looks promising.